# How to Log In a G Suite User Automatically By Using Service Account?

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, google-admin-sdk

Our PHP app has a number of users, for the sake of argument, let's say 100.

Users are broken down into groups of let's say 20 users group, giving us 5 groups.

Using the Google Admin API, Calendar and a service account, I have created one Google user per group. The point here is that this Google user is a not a person and does not map directly to an app user; it has a generic username/email of something like "group_proxy1@domain.com" and a random password.

Each Google user has a calendar; this is the key to this whole line of development. Essentially the goal is to create a shared calendar -- each of the 20 app users in a group, are to share the calendar.

The desired flow is that when an app user logs into our app, he can click a button and automatically be logged into our G Suite Service and view the appropriate calendar.

I have done lots of searching for a solution and they all seem to involve SAML, SSO, Google ID etc. In itself, this is not a problem, however, each of these solutions as part of their flow at some point present the app user with a login screen. Keep in mind, the app user does not know the generic username and password.

I am looking for a examples/pointers where the service account could construct the appropriate link and login flow, such that when an app user clicks the link, he is logged in to our G Suite hosted service for the appropriate Google proxy user.

Comment: Well, you can start to check/read the Google documentation of [Service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount). You will learn here the meaning, use and the possible ways that you can use the service account with your application. Also, this documentation explains how to prepare in making an authorized API call and how to call a Google API.

Comment: @KENdi Perhaps my question is not clear enough. I said that I am using a service account successful with the API. I can create users, calendars, events, contacts all via the API. These are all server to server API activities.

My question is about the possibility of logging a user in via a button/link (i.e. a client based session) without the intermediary screen because as I say in my question, app users don't know the credentials. 

I checked your profile and you seem experienced w/ the G Suite API; I'd hope with that experience you could point someone to the specifics of their question.